# AppCenter.ms Android build variants incompatible with actual gradle

Tags: android, gradle, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to setup `AppCenter` for my current project. I found that build variants that `AppCenter` suggest not exist in my `build.gradle` and so I can't build my project.

How can I fix my `build.gradle` or `AppCenter`?

Here is example of AppCenter variants:

[image]

And actual Android Studio variants:

[image]

My shorten `build.gradle`

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {}
    }

    productFlavors {
        internal {}
        production {}
    }

    buildTypes {
        develop {}
        rc {}
        release {}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste  your build.gradle file?

Comment: rcRelease in AppCenter does not make sense. Please try importing again. Also have you given flavordimensions?